# Return maximum of conditionally selected pairs from a vector in R

Tags: r, vector, conditional-statements, max, pairwise

Reproducible example:

```
set.seed(1)
A <- round(runif(12, min = 1, max = 5))

> A
 [1] 1 2 2 4 3 4 3 4 5 3 4 5

expectedResult <- c(max(A[1], A[4]), max(A[2], A[5]), max(A[3], A[6]), max(A[7], A[10]), max(A[8], A[11]), max(A[9], A[12]))

> expectedResult
[1] 4 3 4 3 4 5
```

Each A needs to be considered as a collection of segments with 6 elements. For example, A here has 2 segments such as A[1:6] and A[7:12]. For each segment, the first 3 elements are compared with the next 3 elements. Therefore I need to take `max(A[1],A[4])`, `max(A[2], A[5])`, `max(A[2], A[5])`, `max(A[3], A[6])`, `max(A[7], A[10])`, `max(A[8], A[11])`, `max(A[9], A[12])`.

My original vector has way more elements than this example and therefore I need a much simpler approach to do this. In addition, speed is also a factor for the original calculation and therefore looking for a fast solution as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could create a function to `split` the vector by 'n' elements, loop over the `list`, create a `matrix` with `nrow` specified as 2, use `pmax` to do `elementwise` max after converting to `data.frame`, return the output by `unlist`ing the `list`

```
f1 <- function(vec, n) {
       lst1 <- split(vec, as.integer(gl(length(vec), n, length(vec))))
       unname(unlist(lapply(lst1, function(x) 
       do.call(pmax, as.data.frame(t(matrix(x, nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)))))))
}
```

-output

```
> f1(A, 6)
[1] 4 3 4 3 4 5
```

---

If the length is not a multiple of 3 or 6, another option is to do a group by operation with `tapply` after splitting

```
unname(unlist(lapply(split(A, as.integer(gl(length(A), 6, 
    length(A)))), function(x) tapply(x, (seq_along(x)-1) %% 3 + 1, FUN = max))))
[1] 4 3 4 3 4 5
```

#### data

```
A <- c(1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option in base R:

```
a <- 6
unlist(tapply(A, gl(length(A)/a, a),
  function(x) pmax(head(x, a/2), tail(x, a/2))),, FALSE)
[1] 4 3 4 3 4 5
```

or even

```
a <- 6
unlist(tapply(A, gl(length(A)/a, a),
  function(x) do.call(pmax, data.frame(matrix(x, ncol = 2)))),, FALSE)
[1] 4 3 4 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reshape the vector to a 3d array, split by column, and take the parallel max.  This should be pretty efficient as far as base R goes.

```
do.call(pmax.int, asplit(`dim<-`(A, c(3,2,2)), 2))

[1] 4 3 4 3 4 5
```